# difference between synchronous and asynchronous client

Tags: eclipse, asynchronous, junit, client

While I was reading about automated Junit Test case generation in Eclipse I have come across with this sentence

```
the testcases were generated to test both the synchronous and asynchronous clients.
```

I googled a lot to find the definition of these two terms and the difference between them but couldn't find any appropriate answer.

Could anyone please explain what is synchronous and asynchronous clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [EAI Patterns](http://www.eaipatterns.com/ComposedMessagingWS.html):

> In a synchronous implementation of a Web Service, the client connection remains open from the time the request is submitted to the server. The client will wait until the server sends back the response message....
>   At the present time, most Web Services toolkits only support synchronous messaging by default. However, using existing standards and tools such as asynchronous message queuing frameworks, some vendors have emulated asynchronous messaging for Web Services.

In asynchronous clients, clients should be able to handle incoming data from server after server has done its job. Asynchronous requests are like *'fire and forget'* mechanism. Target will inform you about the progress.